# JAVAX evaluates xpath expression using root instead of child

Tags: java, xpath

```
public class Test {

    // create an XPathFactory
    XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    // create an XPath object
    XPath xpath = xFactory.newXPath();
...

String sample = "<node>"
        + "<child2><page>555</page></child2>"
        + "<child1>"
        + "<page>655</page>"
        + "</child1>"
        + "</node>";
...
Element child1 = (Element)root.getElementsByTagName("child1").item(0);
page = (String)xpath.evaluate("//page", child1,XPathConstants.STRING);
```

vs

```
page = (String)xpath.evaluate(".//page", child1,XPathConstants.STRING);
```

One will return 555, the other 655. How is it evaluating at the root if I am evaluating using child1 element. I was mistaken in believing all evaluations would be evaluated in the specified context of child1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "/" or "//" at the start of a path means that the selection is from the root of the tree containing the context item.

Comment: That I understand. Wondering how possible if it is evaluating using child1, a child element which is no longer  root.

Comment: In the XDM data model it is always possible to navigate upwards from any node to the root of the tree.